# Syntax of the JSON body in CURL call to a REST API

Tags: json, rest, api, curl, escaping

When I try to send a curl req from terminal on OSX as:

curl --anyauth --user usr:pwd -X PUT  -d ‘{"events":{"event":"Database Replicate"}}’ -i -H "Content-type: application/json" URL

it gives me below error:

{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"XDMP-JSONDOC", "message":"XDMP-JSONDOC: xdmp:unquote(\"‘{events:{event:Database Replicate}}’\", (), \"format-json\") -- Document is not JSON"}}

I tried to escape the quotes, ensured its UTF-8, still doesn't work. When I simply save it in a file and then attach as -d@filename.json to the CURL req, it just works.

Any idea if I am missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question. I'm using macOS Sierra.

Comment: Are you using the correct single quote? I just copied the body and it have apostrophe (’) instead of prime symbol (')

Comment: I was typing it myself but writing the req in 'Notes' app on macOS before copy-pasting it on the terminal. Notes app turns your default (') into (’). I think I shouldn't be using that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typing the request directly on terminal solved the issue. Do not trust on any 3rd party app when it comes to encoding.